# Things that I should have to start using Mathematica

Tags: mathematica-online

What are the things that I must have to start using Mathematica from begining?

Comment: A computer and a _Mathematica_ licence...?

Comment: You do not need a Mathematica licence to use Mathematica. It is available free online to try  [http://develop.open.wolframcloud.com/objects/wpc-welcome/ThingsToTry.nb](http://develop.open.wolframcloud.com/objects/wpc-welcome/ThingsToTry.nb)  The main site is [http://develop.open.wolframcloud.com/app/](http://develop.open.wolframcloud.com/app/)

Comment: One of the things I love about Mathematica is that the overheads are so low. There's very little you _must_ have. Perhaps a willingness to dive in and explore the (very good) documentation. Also, for me, I found that having an enormous project I could obsess about was a must.